# TFS 2012 Code Review using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I cannot seem to use the new features that come with TFS 2012 using VS 2010?

Is it possible? I would like to use the code review feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Reviews require visual studio 2012 and tfs 2012. VS2010 simply does not have the built in UI to support doing them.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create an account on TFS:

https://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/ #

There is an option

> "Beginner's guide A step-by-step guide to help you get up and running
>   now. "

There you will find a step by step, I followed and am getting use normally.
In my case I have to upgrade:

> "If you have not already, install Visual Studio 2012. You can use
>   Visual Studio 2010, but you'll need to install Service Pack 1 first
>   and KB2662296. Or, you can use Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with GDR this
>   update. "

After that I could use normally.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a form of code review possible with VS2010 from the CMMI process, but it doesn't have the nice interactive and code-commenting features from VS2012, it is just another Work Item form.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332483%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).